# Calculate persistence of sign in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

This is hard to describe so consider this example. Let's say I have this array

```
import numpy as np
X=np.array([-1.94198425,  2.29219632,  0.35505434,
   -0.06408812, -1.25963731, -0.32275248, -0.4178637 ,  0.37951672])
```

Now I want to count the number of times (number of consecutive indices) that the sign of the elements remain the same. In this case the answer would be `[1, 2, 4, 1]`, because there's 1 negative number, followed by 2 positive numbers, followed by 4 negatives and so on. I can calculate this by doing

```
times=[0]
sig=np.sign(X[0])
for x in X:
    if sig==np.sign(x):
        times[-1]+=1
    else:
        times.append(1)
    sig=np.sign(x)
print(times)
```

Which yields the correct result.

However, if I have a `400x1000` array and I want to perform this over one of the axes things get pretty slow.

Is there any way to use Numpy/Scipy to do this easily and over on axis of an n-dimensional array?

I figured I could start with something like

```
a=X.copy()
a[a<=0]=-1
a[a>0]=1
```

And use stuff like `cumsum()` but so far I got nothing.

PS: I could probably use f2py, Cython or Numba, but I'm trying to avoid that because of flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Vectorized one-liner solution -

```
np.diff(np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.sign(X))!=0)+1, len(X)])
```

**Approach #2 :** Alternatively, for some performance boost, we can make use of `slicing` to replace the differentiation on the sign values and use faster `np.concatenate` in place of `np.r_` for the concatenation step, like so -

```
s = np.sign(X)
out = np.diff(np.concatenate(( [0], np.flatnonzero(s[1:]!=s[:-1])+1, [len(X)] )))
```

**Approach #3 :** Alternatively again, if the number of sign changes is a considerable number as compared to the length of the input array, you might want to do the concatenation on the mask array of sign change. The mask arrays/boolean arrays being much more memory efficient than `int or float` arrays might bring about more performance boost.

Thus, one more method would be -

```
s = np.sign(X)
mask = np.concatenate(( [True], s[1:]!=s[:-1], [True] ))
out = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(mask))
```

---

### Extending to `2D` case

We can extend the approach #3 to a `2D` array case with a bit more of additional work that are explained alongwith the code comments. Good thing is that the concatenation part lets us keep the code vectorized during the extension work. Thus, on a `2D` array for which we need the sign persistence on a per row basis, the implementation would look something like this -

```
# Get signs. Get one-off shifted mask for each row. 
# Concatenate at either ends of each row with True values, getting us 2D mask
s = np.sign(X)
T = np.ones((X.shape[0],1),dtype=bool)
mask2D = np.column_stack(( T, s[:,1:]!=s[:,:-1], T ))

# Get flattened nonzeros indices on the 2D mask. 
all_intervals = np.diff(np.flatnonzero(mask2D.ravel()))

# We need to remove the indices that were generated because of the True values
# concatenation. So, get those indices and delete those.
rm_idx = (mask2D[:-1].sum(1)-1).cumsum() 
all_intervals1 = np.delete(all_intervals, rm_idx + np.arange(X.shape[0]-1))

# Finally, split the indices into a list of arrays, with each array giving us
# the counts of sign persistences
out = np.split(all_intervals1, rm_idx )
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [212]: X
Out[212]: 
array([[-3,  1, -3, -2,  2,  3, -3,  1,  1, -1],
       [-2, -3,  0, -2, -2,  0,  3, -1, -2,  2],
       [ 0, -1, -3, -2, -2,  3, -3, -2,  1,  1],
       [ 1, -3,  0, -1, -2,  1, -1,  1,  3,  2],
       [-1,  1,  0, -2,  0, -1, -1, -3,  0,  1]])

In [213]: out
Out[213]: 
[array([1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]),
 array([2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]),
 array([1, 4, 1, 2, 2]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1])]
```